# How can I get absolute difference of two numbers?

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

Is there any bash/shell command to get absolute difference of two numbers? Eg.-

Absolute diff of `-10 and -5 is 5`, `-10 and 10 is 20`, `7 and 21 is 14` & `100 and -11 is 111`.

Or any workaroud to find it? Please help.

Comment: Why did you tag `Python`, if you want shell commands?

Comment: @thefourtheye Thought if not bash, python will surely help!

Comment: Please include that information as well in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the simple one:

```
echo $(($1-$2)) | sed 's/-//'
./script.sh -10 -5
```

output

```
5
```

The logic is pretty simple. You provide parameters `$1` and `$2` to your script like 
`./script.sh -10 -5` and then output result of `$1 - $2` using `echo`. `sed`
 will delete `-` if it is presented.

Comment: @SandyElms- Tell me the logic please

Answer (score 4):

You can do simple integer arithmetic directly in the shell using the `$((...))` syntax.

```sh
function abs_diff {
    local diff
    diff=$(($1 - $2));
    if [ $diff -lt 0 ]
    then
        diff=$((-$diff))
    fi
    echo $diff
}
```

It can be written more tersely as a single expression using the ternary `?` operator.

```sh
function abs_diff {
    echo $(($1 >= $2 ? $1 - $2 : $2 - $1))
}
```

Then simply use

```sh
abs_diff -10 -5
```

in your code.

**Update:** *“It would be great if you could explain the logic.”* — There we go…

The basic idea is that we write a Bash function that takes two integers as arguments and returns the absolute difference of them.

A Bash function can be called like an external program using the `FUNCTION_NAME [ARG...]` syntax.  Inside a function, we can refer to its arguments via `$1`, `$2`, … just as we refer to a shell script's arguments outside of any function.  To “return” a value from a function, we print it to standard output.  (Don't abuse the `return` statement for that.  It is intended to report success or failure, not business data.)  If we want to assign the result of a function call to  a variable, we can use the `VAR=$(COMMAND [ARG...])` syntax.  A function definition has the syntax `function FUNCTION_NAME { FUNCTION_BODY }`.  If we declare variables that should be local to a function, we can use the `local` keyword.  This is a Bash feature.

Now let's see how we can compute the absolute value of the difference.  We only have integer arithmetic so how can we do it?  Obviously, if we subtract an integer *n* from an integer *m*, there are only two possible outcomes: a non-negative or a negative result.  In the first case, we are done.  In the second, all we need to do is to take the negative.

The first function does exactly this.

```sh
function abs_diff {           # Define the function 'abs_diff'
    local diff                # with 'diff' as a local variable
    diff=$(($1 - $2));        # to compute the difference of its first two arguments
    if [ $diff -lt 0 ]        # and if it is negative
    then                      # then
        diff=$((-$diff))      # negate the result
    fi                        # and
    echo $diff                # finally print the result.
}
```

The second version is more terse.  If you know the ternary `?` operator for example from C or Java, then it will come at no surprise.  What this line

```sh
echo $(($1 >= $2 ? $1 - $2 : $2 - $1))
```

means is: If `$1 >= $2` evaluates to true, then print `$1 - $2`, otherwise `$2 - $1`, which ensures that the result will always be non-negative.

If your need is a one-time thing and defining a function seems like overkill to you, simply copying the body of the second function to the place where it is needed might be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute Python commands, from the command line with [`-c` parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c). So, you can make use of it, like this

```
python -c "import sys; print(abs(int(sys.argv[1]) - int(sys.argv[2])))" 100 -11
# 111
```

This script gets two arguments from the command line, converts both of them to integers, subtracts second value from the first value and prints the absolute value of the result

Answer (score 2):

How about this bash implementation:

```
export A=5
export B=10
echo "$A-$B" | bc | tr -d -
```

#### Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for non-integer numbers also using `bc`.

```
function abs_diff {
    if [ $(bc <<<"$1 >= $2") -eq 1 ]; then
        diff="$(echo $1 - $2 | bc)"
    else
        diff="$(echo $2 - $1 | bc)"
    fi
    
    echo $diff
}

abs_diff 5.0 1.0  #gives output: 4.0
abs_diff 1.0 5.0  #gives output: 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without any external command by using `${var#-}`.

> `${var#Pattern}` Remove from `$var` the shortest part of `$Pattern` that matches the front end of `$var`. [tdlp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

---

Example:

```
s2=7; s1=8
s3=$((s1-s2))

echo $s3
-1

echo ${s3#-}
1
```